# Qual a diferença entre despercebido e desapercebido?

Tags: significado

Qual é a diferença entre as palavras *despercebido* e *desapercebido*?

Comment: Eu penso que este tipo de questões poderiam ser resolvidas com uma pequena consulta no [dicionário](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/).

Comment: @RebeloX Eu comecei por partilhar da tua opinião, e depois de investigar mudei. Por exemplo, o dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa e a Infopédia dão definições que estariam corretas há 3 séculos, mas que não refletem o uso literário dos últimos 200 anos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Desapercebido** = Significa algo ou alguém que não está preparado, desprovido.

> Exemplo: *O programador está desapercebido com relação a linguagem `X`.*

---

**Despercebido** = Algo ou alguém que não chamou a atenção, que não foi sentido, notado, visto.

> Exemplo: *A falta de comprometimento do funcionário não passou despercebida.*

Answer (score 8):

***Desapercebido*** e ***despercebido*** partilham dois significados: (a) em que não se repara; (b) que não se apercebe do que se passa à sua volta, distraído. ***Desapercebido*** significa ainda ***desprovido*** (de provisões, dinheiro, etc.). Vem de um significado antigo de [***aperceber***, que é segundo o Aulete digital:](http://www.aulete.com.br/aperceber)

> **3.** Pôr(-se) em condições de; preparar-se para (tarefa, missão etc.) [td. : *O capitão mandou **aperceber** os soldados*.] [tdr. + para ***Aperceber** as tropas para a luta: **aperceber–se** para a missão espacial*.]
> **4.** P.ext. Guarnecer(-se) do que for necessário; PROVER(-SE) [td. ***aperceber** o navio*.] [tdr. + de : ***Apercebeu** a esquadra de armas e munições para uma longa viagem*.]

***Desapercebido*** caiu relativamente em desuso. E no sentido de ***desprovido*** é agora raro. A mais recente ocorrência que encontrei neste [Corpus do Português](http://corpus.byu.edu/) tem mais de cem anos:

> O comandante-em-chefe, sem carretas para o transporte de munições, ***desapercebido*** dos mais elementares recursos, quedava-se, sem deliberar, diante da tropa acampada (Euclides da Cunha, *Sertões*, 1901.)

No sentido (a), em que não se repara, ***despercebido*** é bastante mais comum que ***desapercebido***. Eis alguns exemplos:

> Foi um detalhe que passou ***desapercebido*** no grande escândalo. (Eça de Queiroz, *Os Maias*, 1888.)
>
> Estava completamente fascinado por ele. Não acho que isso tenha lhe passado ***despercebido***. (Bernardo Carvalho, *Os Bêbados e os Sonâmbulos*, 1996).

No sentido (b), que não se apercebe do que que está à sua volta, quer ***desapercebido*** quer ***despercebido*** são pouco usados. Alguns exemplos:

> Por aí corria uma goteira no tempo da chuva e, embaixo, o assoalho podre ameaçava tragar quem se aproximasse ***despercebido***. (Afonso Arinos, «Assombramento», in *Pelo Sertão*, 1898.)
>
> [D]isfarçou a reparar nas estatuetas de alabastro e vasos de porcelana colocados no mármore vermelho dos consolos. Assim de costas para a conversadeira, mostrava-se ***desapercebida*** daquele enlevo de Aurélia, José de Alencar, Senhora

O [Aulete na entrada ***despercebido***](http://www.aulete.com.br/despercebido) nota que os puristas condenam o uso de ***desapercebido*** na aceção (a) acima, *em que não se repara*, mas que este uso é observado em autores de nomeada. Na verdade é sobretudo nesta aceção que ***desapercebido*** foi usado na literatura nos últimos duzentos e tal anos. Neste [Corpus do Português](http://corpus.byu.edu/) no conjunto dos séculos XIX e XX, ***desapercebido*** ocorre com o significado de ***desprovido*** duas vezes; de ***desprevenido*** duas vezes; de ***distraído*** cinco vezes; e de ***em que não se repara*** 38 vezes, 34 das quais na forma ***passar desapercebido***. Os puristas teriam de recuar ao século XVIII ou XVII para encontrar ***desapercebido*** empregue ao gosto deles.

Comment: Li isto tantas vezes que já nem sei o que mais uso e em que situações... Que confusão...

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu nem sequer sabia da existência de *desapercebido*. Fui investigar por causa desta pergunta. É uma palavra muito rara. Nos últimos dois séculos basicamente, *desapercebido* e *despercebido* foram usados como sinónimos. Até encontrei um *despercebido* usado 'erradamente' no sentido de *desprovido* (que compara com dois *desapercebidos* usados 'corretamente' nesse sentido no mesmo período). Portanto não te rales.